# MySQL: Select rows with more than one occurrence

Tags: mysql

Here's my query. It selects a list of ids from two tables across two databases. The query works fine.

```
select en.id, fp.blogid
from french.blog_pics fp, french.blog_news fn, english.blog_news en 
where fp.blogid = fn.id 
and en.title_fr = fn.title 
and fp.title != ''
```

I  only want to display rows where a `en.id` occurs more than once

So for instance, if this was the current query result

```
en.id fp.blogid
---------------
  10     12
  12     8
  17     9
  12     8
```

I only want to query to show this instead

```
 en.id fp.blogid occurrences
 -----------------------------
  12     8           2
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
select en.id, fp.blogid, count(*) as occurrences
from french.blog_pics fp, french.blog_news fn, english.blog_news en 
where fp.blogid = fn.id 
and en.title_fr = fn.title 
and fp.title != ''
group by en.id
having count(*) > 1
```