# MySQL - Count only unique instances between specific dates

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I've been looking at several other SO questions but I could not make out a solution from these. First, the description, then what I'm missing from the other threads. (Heads up: I'm very well aware of the non-normalised structure of our database, which is something I have addressed in meetings before but this is what we have and what I have to work with.)

**Background description**

We have a machine that manufactures products in 25 positions. These products' production data is being logged in a table that among other things logs current and voltage for every position.  This is only logged when the machine is actually producing products (i.e. has a product in the machine). The time where no product is present, nothing is being logged.

This machine can run in two different production modes: full production and R&D production. Full production means that products are being inserted continuously so that every instance has a product at all times (i.e. 25 products are present in the machine at all times). The second mode, R&D production, only produces one product at a time (i.e. one product enters the machine, goes through the 25 instances one by one and when this one is finished, the second product enters the machine).

To clarify: every position logs data once every second whenever a product is present, which means 25 instances per second when full production is running. When R&D mode is running, position 1 will have ~20 instances for 20 consecutive seconds, position 2 will have ~20 instances for the next 20 consecutive seconds and so on.

**Table structure**

Productiondata:

- id (autoincrement)
- productID
- position
- time (timestamp for logged data)
- current (amperes)
- voltage (volts)

**Question**

We want to calculate the uptime of the machine, but we want to separate the uptime for production mode and R&D mode, and we want to separate this data on a weekly basis.

**Guessed solution**

Since we have instances logged every second I can count the amount of DISTINCT instances of time values we have in the table to find out the total uptime for both production and R&D mode. To find the R&D mode, I can safely say that whenever there is a time instance that has only one entry, I'm running in R&D mode (production mode would have 25 instances).

**Progress so far**

I have the following query which sums up all distinct instances to find both production and R&D mode:

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(time) AS YWeek, COUNT(DISTINCT time) AS Time_Seconds, ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT time)/3600, 1) AS Time_Hours 
FROM Database.productiondata
WHERE YEARWEEK(time) >= YEARWEEK(curdate()) - 21
GROUP BY YWeek;
```

This query finds out how many DISTINCT time instances there are in the table and counts the number and groups that by the week.

**Problem**

The above query counts the amount of instances that exist in the table, but I want to find ONLY the UNIQUE instances. Basically, I'm trying to find something like IF count(time) = 1, then count that instance, IF count(time) > 1 then don't count it at all (DISTINCT still counts this).

I looked at several other SO threads, but almost all explain how to find unique values with DISTINCT, which only accomplishes half of what I'm looking for. The closest I got was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242990/mysql-select-rows-with-more-than-one-occurrence) which uses a HAVING clause. I'm currently stuck at the following:

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(time) as YWeek, COUNT(Distinct time) As Time_Seconds, ROUND(COUNT(Distinct time)/3600, 1) As Time_Hours
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM Database.productiondata
WHERE time > '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY time
HAVING count(time) = 1) as temptime
GROUP BY YWeek
ORDER BY YWeek;
```

The problem here is that we have a GROUP BY time inside the nested select clause which takes forever (~5 million rows only for this year so I can understand that). I mean, syntactically I think that this is correct but it takes forever to exectue. Even EXPLAIN for this times out.

And that is where I am. Is this the correct approach or is there any other way that is smarter/requires less query time/avoids the group by time clause?

**EDIT:** As a sample, we have this table (apologies for formatting, don't know how to make a table format here on SO)

```
id    position    time
1     1           1
2     2           1
3     5           1
4     19          1
...   ...         ...
25    7           1
26    3           2
27    6           2
...   ...         ...
```

This table shows how it looks like when there is a production run going on. As you can see, there is no general structure for which position gets the first entry when logging the data in the table; what happens is that the 25 positions gets logged during every second and the data is then added to the table depending on how fast the PLC sends the data for every position. The following table shows how the table looks like when it runs in research mode.

```
id    position    time
245   1           1
246   1           2
247   1           3
...   ...         ...
269   1           25
270   2           26
271   2           27
...   ...         ...
```

Since all the data is consolidated into one single table, we want to find out how many instances there are when COUNT(time) is exactly equal to 1, or we could look for every instance when COUNT(time) is strictly larger than 1.

**EDIT2:** As a reply to Alan, the suggestion gives me

```
YWeek    Time_Seconds    Time_Hours
201352   1               0.0
201352   1               0.0
201352   1               0.0
...      ...             ...
201352   1               0.0  (1000 row limit)
```

Whereas my desired output is

```
Yweek    Time_Seconds    Time_Hours
201352   2146            35.8
201401   5789            96.5
...      ...             ...
201419   8924            148.7
```

**EDIT3:** I have gathered the tries and the results so far [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRRFr.png) with a description in gray above the queries.

Comment: I'm confused. I cannot see the 'normalisation' flaw in this!?!?

Comment: I added that comment as a precaution since my earlier questions here with similar structuring said "why do you not have a separate table with the positions in it? Why are they in the same table?" and such :)

Comment: Thank you for the update, I replied below with the additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might achieve better results by eliminating your sub select:

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(time) as YWeek, 
       COUNT(time) As Time_Seconds, 
       ROUND(COUNT(time)/3600, 1) As Time_Hours
FROM Database.productiondata
WHERE time > '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY YWeek
HAVING count(time) = 1)
ORDER BY YWeek;
```

I'm assuming `time` has an `index` on it, but if it does not you could expect a significant improvement in performance by adding one.

**UPDATE:**

Per the recently added sample data, I'm not sure your approach is correct.  The `time` column appears to be an `INT` representing seconds while you're treating it as a `DATETIME` with `YEARWEEK`.  Below I have a working example in SQL that does exactly what you asked IF `time` is actually a `DATETIME` column:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
    (
      id INT ,
      [position] INT ,
      [time] DATETIME
    )


INSERT  INTO @table
VALUES  ( 1, 1, DATEADD(week, -1, GETDATE()) )
INSERT  INTO @table
VALUES  ( 1, 1, DATEADD(week, -2, GETDATE()) )
INSERT  INTO @table
VALUES  ( 1, 1, DATEADD(week, -2, GETDATE()) )
INSERT  INTO @table
VALUES  ( 1, 1, DATEADD(week, -2, GETDATE()) )
INSERT  INTO @table
VALUES  ( 1, 1, DATEADD(week, -2, GETDATE()) )
INSERT  INTO @table
VALUES  ( 1, 1, DATEADD(week, -3, GETDATE()) )
INSERT  INTO @table
VALUES  ( 1, 1, DATEADD(week, -3, GETDATE()) )

SELECT  CAST(DATEPART(year, [time]) AS VARCHAR)
        + CAST(DATEPART(week, [time]) AS VARCHAR) AS YWeek ,
        COUNT([time]) AS Time_Seconds ,
        ROUND(COUNT([time]) / 3600, 1) AS Time_Hours
FROM    @table
WHERE [time] > '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY DATEPART(year, [time]) ,
        DATEPART(week, [time])
HAVING COUNT([time]) > 0
ORDER BY YWeek;
```

Comment: It significantly reduces the query time! The problem is that by doing this I get one row for every time instance whereas I'm only interested in grouping them by week. It gives me one row for every second (since it groups by time as well as week). It's like I want the output of this query, and then count the amount of instances there are for every week in the result, but I'm not sure how that query would look like.

Comment: I've updated my answer to invert the grouping to `YWEEK, TIME`.  If I understand correctly, this should in theory get you the grouping you want.  If you truly only want grouping by `WEEK`, then remove the `, TIME` grouping all together.

Comment: Still getting the same result :S I'm wondering if this is because it does it in the same query? Like, I would first have to get all the instances HAVING count(time) = 1 and then after I have that data in my output, I use the new dataset to group it by the weeks?

Comment: Can you possibly provide some sample data in the original question paired with the desired output?  Also I should mention if you remove the `, TIME` grouping you would need to use an aggregate function on `YEARWEEK(MAX(time))` and `ROUND(COUNT(Distinct MAX(time))/3600, 1)`.

Comment: Will do, but that will have to be later tonight, let me get back to you on this.

Comment: Apologies for not getting back to you sooner as I've been away with work for a few days. I've added sample data from our table, the result that your suggested query gives and what the desired output is. It seems that the GROUP BY time is not working as it should, although your suggestion is very close to what I'm looking for. Now when you see the output of the query, do you know what could be causing this mishap?

Comment: My apologies for the edit, the column is indeed a DATETIME, but I simplified it here by only using integers as a representation. I tried to use your query for the example but I can't get it to run (have it inside a DELIMITER $$ and ; statement as well as DECLARE being the first statement right after the BEGIN clause). I get "syntax error, unexpected DECLARE_SYM, expecting END_OF_INPUT or ';'" here. It's the first time I'm using Declare so I might be messing something else up here. I have uploaded how it looks like [here](http://i.imgur.com/J1aZWxC.png).

Comment: I think I will put your answer as the best answer as the first one you suggested actually works for the test database but not for our live one. Since the error seems to be local I'll give you the benefit of the doubt :) Also, our live database went down this morning together with the server and its discs so I'll never be able to verify if it was the query or the database structure. Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT pd1.* 
FROM Database.productiondata pd1
LEFT JOIN Database.productiondata pd2 ON pd1.time=pd2.time AND pd1.id<pd2.id
WHERE pd1.time > '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND pd2.time > '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
  AND pd2.id IS NULL
```

You can `LEFT JOIN` to the same table and leave only the rows with no related

UPDATE The query works using the SQL fiddle

```
SELECT pd1.* From productiondata pd1
left Join productiondata pd2
ON pd1.time = pd2.time and pd1.id < pd2.id
Where pd1.time > '2014-01-01 00:00:00' and pd2.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you're doing here. What are you referring to with pd1 and pd2?

Comment: `pd1` and `pd2` are table aliases, they allow you to compare `productiondata` against itself.

Comment: This query gives me "time in where clause is ambiguous" so I tried to change that to pd1.time (the query times out) and pd2.time (quick but gives 0 results). To clarify (i.e. to see if I understand this correctly): this query creates two temporary tables (pd1 and pd2), it then takes the instances where time is equal in both tables but only when there are at least two instances of this time. This query is only executed for dates during 2014, but I don't follow on the last "and pd2.id is null" statement - is this correctly understood?

Comment: Replace the time condition check with pd1.time>'2014-01-01 00:00:00' and pd2.time>'2014-01-01 00:00:00'

Comment: That query gives me 0 results again :S I will add a sample data on what I'm getting as opposed to what I'm looking for later tonight when I'm off work.

Comment: I've been away for 2 days with work and I apologise for not updating sooner. I talked to one of the programmers and he explained the structure of your suggestion since I couldn't quite grasp it. I think that the comparison with itself is a brilliant idea! But the query gives me 0 results and I'm still not quite in the clear on how this query actually works. The AND pd1.id<pd2.id is together with the WHERE AND pd2.id IS NULL is what puzzles me. How is this different from a GROUP BY time HAVING count(time) = 1?

Comment: Suppose there is just one record with the same time. Then < will eliminate it from the joined table. There will be not matched record. Thus pd2.id will be null. If there are more than 1 record with the same time one of them will have bigger id. Thus the record with bigger id will have match with smaller id and the same time. Thus pd2.id won't be null.

Comment: I see how that should work, but I tried this on a test database, and it still gives me the records for both the multiple instances and for the single instances. I have uploaded a picture of it [here](http://i.imgur.com/FdDvUgv.png) to illustrate what happens. I understand now how the query should run, but it seems to be something else I'm missing.

Comment: Thank you for being patient with me :) I have created an SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa5c5/2). This shows how the query gives me 0 results, and I'm not really sure why.

Comment: Thank you, although the updated answer gives me one position for every instance, even those with a COUNT > 1 (it gives me 4 results). I'm trying to rework that query to give me only the results where the COUNT is exactly equal to 1 (should be only three rows in this example). I think I solved it however, since a similar query to what Alan suggested seems to work on the test database. Unfortunately our database server went down at work this morning so I can't test it on the real database for a few days.