# Select rows from joined tables with more than n occurrence

Tags: postgresql, join, group-by, count

My problem is similar with [MySQL: Select rows with more than one occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4242990/6666231) but I am using PostgreSQL. I have a query like:

```
select d.user_id, d.recorded_at, d.glucose_value, d.unit
from diary as d
join (
    select u.id
    from health_user as u
    join (
        select distinct user_id
        from care_connect
        where clinic_id = 217
            and role = 'user'
            and status = 'active'
    ) as c
    on u.id = c.user_id
    where u.is_tester is false
) as cu
on d.user_id = cu.id
where d.created_at >= d.recorded_at
    and d.recorded_at < current_date and d.recorded_at >= current_date - interval '30 days'
    and d.glucose_value > 0
    and (d.state = 'wakeup' or (d.state = 'before_meal' and d.meal_type = 'breakfast'))
```

The result looks like:

```
+---------+---------------------+---------------+--------+
| user_id |     recorded_at     | glucose_value |  unit  |
+---------+---------------------+---------------+--------+
|   12041 | 2018-06-26 01:10:12 |           100 | mg/dL  |
|   12041 | 2018-06-30 02:10:11 |            90 | mg/dL  |
|   12214 | 2018-06-25 12:40:13 |            10 | mmol/L |
|   12214 | 2018-06-26 12:41:13 |            12 | mmol/L |
|   12214 | 2018-06-29 00:21:14 |            11 | mmol/L |
|   12214 | 2018-06-29 12:59:32 |            10 | mmol/L |
+---------+---------------------+---------------+--------+
```

As you can see that is already a long query with many conditions. Now I want to get only the records that are from users who have no less than four records (rows) in the result, so I tried:

```
select d.user_id, d.recorded_at, d.glucose_value, d.unit, count(d.*)
from diary as d
join (
    select u.id
    from health_user as u
    join (
        select distinct user_id
        from care_connect
        where clinic_id = 217
            and role = 'user'
            and status = 'active'
    ) as c
    on u.id = c.user_id
    where u.is_tester is false
) as cu
on d.user_id = cu.id
where d.created_at >= d.recorded_at
    and d.recorded_at < current_date and d.recorded_at >= current_date - interval '30 days'
    and d.glucose_value > 0
    and (d.state = 'wakeup' or (d.state = 'before_meal' and d.meal_type = 'breakfast'))
group by d.user_id
having count(d.*) >= 4
```

My expected output is:

```
+---------+---------------------+---------------+--------+
| user_id |     recorded_at     | glucose_value |  unit  |
+---------+---------------------+---------------+--------+
|   12214 | 2018-06-25 12:40:13 |            10 | mmol/L |
|   12214 | 2018-06-26 12:41:13 |            12 | mmol/L |
|   12214 | 2018-06-29 00:21:14 |            11 | mmol/L |
|   12214 | 2018-06-29 12:59:32 |            10 | mmol/L |
+---------+---------------------+---------------+--------+
```

However, it throws an error, saying that `d.recorded_at` should also be added in `group by`, but that's not what I want. Besides grouping raw timestamps is not meaningful.

I know I can probably join another table, which are generated by the same query but only `select d.user_id, count(d.*)` at the first line, but the whole query would look crazy.

Would somebody please help me how to achieve this in a better way? Sorry I don't put table structures here, but I can edit and clarify things if needed.

Comment: Please add the first query actual output and expected output.

Comment: @FahadAnjum Have edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Select user_id, recorded_at, glucose_value, unit
From (
select d.user_id, d.recorded_at, d.glucose_value, d.unit, count(1) over (partition by d.user_id) rcnt
from diary as d
join (
    select u.id
    from health_user as u
    join (
        select distinct user_id
        from care_connect
        where clinic_id = 217
            and role = 'user'
            and status = 'active'
    ) as c
    on u.id = c.user_id
    where u.is_tester is false
) as cu
on d.user_id = cu.id
where d.created_at >= d.recorded_at
    and d.recorded_at < current_date and d.recorded_at >= current_date - interval '30 days'
    and d.glucose_value > 0
    and (d.state = 'wakeup' or (d.state = 'before_meal' and d.meal_type = 'breakfast'))
) x 
Where rcnt >= 4
```

Comment: What does `count(1)` mean and what is `over (partition by d.user_id)`? Would you please add more explanation in your answer?

Comment: () Over () is analytical function. We can use this when we need detail report with aggregated value. eg. I need employee wise salary but want to know total salary paying to that employee department. In this case we can use analytical function.  

"Count" will work with group by clause. So we can't get the detail result. 

In your case you want detail but same time you want to count number of records. In this case analytical function only will be useful to you. Otherwise you have to use sub query and it will be complex and will raise performance issue

Comment: Thank you. But what is the `1` in `count(1)` then?

Comment: nothing, its just constant. If we use particular column and if that column is null then count wont consider that. If you use count(*) then it may take time to check all the columns. So to avoid all these we can use count(1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Replace your_query with your actual query.

Using **with clause** and **exists clause**.

```
with original_query as ( your_query )
select * from original_query q1
where 
exists( select q2.user_id from original_query q2 where q1.user_id = q2.user_id
group by q2.user_id 
having count(q2.user_id) >= 4 )
```